# Problems w/ Right aligning navigation and/or making the nav inline with logo

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, navbar

Unable to set the main nav to right align. Please see site: accessatx.com. Also, can it be set to be inline with the logo (under the button)?

Using Wordpress, theme: Avada. Tried float: right in CSS and failed.

Answer (score 0):

change in your css like this

```
.fusion-header-banner{
padding-top: 19px;
}
#menu-main{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

output you get like this

[image: Result]